# Expression in RS VisualBasic

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

So I have an expression inside a cell of a table in my RS via VS2008

- I want to divide X / Z
- The result must have a formatnumber so `FormatNumber((X / Z),2)`
- Z cant be 0 so `IIF(Z = 0,0,FormatNumber((X / Z),2))`
- If X is 0 then the result will be 0,00 I want to avoid that so 
  `IIF(Z = 0 OR X = 0),0,FormatNumber((X / Z),2))`

But what happenes when the result is a whole number? it will look like this 50.00%

What can I do to avoid the formatting when the result is a whole number?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the solution.

It was a replace when you see ",00" just put "" Outside the formatnumber.

Best Regards.